# Visual Studio mixed mode debugging with Linux development

Tags: c#, c++, linux, visual-studio

Given the following scenario:

- Visual Studio 2019/2022
- Solution with two projects (.NET 5 C# console app, native C++ .so) targeting Linux
- WSL or docker linux container runtime

is it possible to mix-debug the code (as it is when targeting windows with the mixed-mode debugging feature)?

If not, is there any VS extension or different IDE I can use for this purpose?

Comment: This is from a year or so ago.  It won't make you happy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545186/how-to-enable-mixed-mode-debugging-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: If you can do it, it would probably be announced on the VS-C++ team blog (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog).  After a quick scan, it doesn't look promising.